# Getting null values when passing data from activity to fragment using Parceable

Tags: android, arrays, android-bundle

I am trying to pass arraylist from activity to fragments but i am getting a null value using the parceable.

In Main Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("cbookings", customerbooking);
                    Todaybooking tb = new Todaybooking();
                    tb.setArguments(bundle);
```

Array list data declarations

```
ArrayList<Cbooking> customerbooking = new ArrayList<>();
```

In fragments:

```
ArrayList<Cbooking> customerbooking = new ArrayList<>();

    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    customerbooking = extras.getParcelableArrayList("cbookings");
    Log.wtf("test", customerbooking.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `setArguments()` to pass the data into the fragment. Therefore, you need to use `getArguments()` to retrieve the data, not `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()`.

Comment: I am still getting null even i have set Bundle extras = getArguments();